# Better way to add route class under the same group

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4

**Route Service Provider code is below**

```
Route::prefix('api/v1')
     ->middleware('api')
     ->namespace($this->namespace)
     ->group(base_path('routes/Login.php'));

Route::prefix('api/v1')
     ->middleware('api')
     ->namespace($this->namespace)
     ->group(base_path('routes/Register.php'));
```

Is there any way to write both route files under the same group?

**Something like this...**

```
Route::prefix('api/v1')
    ->middleware('api')
    ->namespace($this->namespace)
    ->group(base_path('routes/Login.php'))
    ->group(base_path('routes/Register.php'));
```

**In 5.3. we could write like this...**

```
Route::group([
    'middleware'    => 'auth:api',
    'namespace'     => $this->namespace,
    'prefix'        => 'api/v1',
], function ($router) {
    require base_path('routes/API/Driver/Driver.php');
    require base_path('routes/API/Vehicle/Vehicle.php');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `group` method takes a function as argument, so it should just be

```
Route::prefix('api/v1')
    ->middleware('api')
    ->namespace($this->namespace)
    ->group(function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/API/Driver/Driver.php');
        require base_path('routes/API/Vehicle/Vehicle.php');
    });


// routes/API/Driver/Driver.php
<?php

Route::get('/drivers', 'DriverController@method');
// (Route URI is '/api/v1/drivers');
```

Comment: I think, You misunderstood my question....I am trying add multiple php files under same group. Not multiple routes under same group.

Comment: @Pankaj yes, I don't think I get what you want... Can you show an example of one of those php files?

Comment: each php file has their routes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same solution as in 5.3 in 5.4

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', /* .... */], function () {

        // extract this to external files as needed
        Route::get('/path', 'HomeController@method');

    });
```

Comment: Please check the latest 5.4 format mention in my question.

Comment: group() method does not return anything. so you can not chain on it. but as Alejandro said you can pass a closure.